# PHP String to variables

Tags: php

I have

```
$string = "temp";
```

I want extract string value and make new variable (array) :

```
$temp = array();
```

is possible?

Comment: You are looking for [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Use this `$temp[]=$string;` then print `$temp` with `print_r($temp);` You will get result of `$temp` array with value.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari, just to make it clear and for future reference, `$temp[] = $string;` will create an array named `$temp` with the content of `$string` on next position (in this case, probably `0`). It's not the same as creating a variable where it's name is informed as string in another variable. Take a loot at the result of what you suggested: [https://3v4l.org/Mmo5F](https://3v4l.org/Mmo5F). Take a look at the expected: [https://3v4l.org/U4qWv](https://3v4l.org/U4qWv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Example:

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();
var_dump($temp);
var_dump($$string);//Same as var_dump($temp)
```

However I find this can lead to difficult to read code, there is usually other ways to do what you are needing.

Comment: `var_dump($$string);` ;)

Comment: @FirstOne Good point! Have added that too.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can!

`${$string}`

then you can call it like this: $temp;

more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

With this method you can use it in a for loop to create a bunch of variables in no time :)

exemple:
`${'box_'.$i.'_image};`

Comment: I know it's just to show your point, but note: if you know that you can call it like `$temp`, why not use it like so from the beginning? You should continue using `${$string}` everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Variable variables`:

```
$string = "temp";
$$string = array();
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php.